# Using external xml data in a Flex application without compiling the source into the application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

I want to read xml data to a mxml application from a xml file on my filesystem. The example I found was for [AIR](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_16.html),[link2](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_11.html), [link3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html). But I want to target the Flash Player runtime. 
If I use the the  [tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf66ba1-7fff.html), I can do it; however the xml compiles into my swf. How can I retain the xml file in my release build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UrlLoader to load the external xml at runtime. You may need to delay the loading of your app components until the xml has been loaded (depending on the details of your application.)

Comment: is there an example with delay?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. I can't really say much more without seeing your app in more detail. But here's an example of loading an xml file: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_11.html

Comment: I think this is the best way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [mx:HTTPService tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/accessingdata/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html) , as referenced in the link you've provided

Comment: i didn't find any example to use it without any kind of server-side technology. Just load it from a path in the source directory, but don't compile it to the swf

Comment: Then Jacob Eggers' answer is fine. Use the URLLoader class , have a look at the docs for implementation details, but the basic idea is to listen to a complete Event as indication that the XML data is loaded. You can also to to the Adobe website & check the "Flex in a week tutorial", if I remember correctly they have a video tutorial about loading XML data.